Cannot Adjust Privileges for Logon in Windows Credential Provider
I am developing a Windows Credential Provider and I need to programmatically log in a user. However, I am facing issues with setting the required privileges (SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME and SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME). Here is the relevant code and the steps I’ve taken:
SetPrivilage function:
BOOL SetPrivilege(
    HANDLE hToken,          // token handle
    LPCTSTR Privilege,      // Privilege to enable/disable
    BOOL bEnablePrivilege   // TRUE to enable.  FALSE to disable
)
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(
        NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
        Privilege,       // privilege to lookup
        &luid))          // receives LUID of privilege
    {
        logFile << "LookupPrivilegeValue Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return FALSE;
    }

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = (bEnablePrivilege) ? SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED : 0;

    // Enable the privilege or disable all privileges.
    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(
        hToken,
        FALSE,
        &tp,
        sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
        (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL,
        (PDWORD)NULL))
    {
        logFile << "AdjustTokenPrivileges error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)
    {
        logFile << "The token does not have the specified privilege: " << Privilege << std::endl;
        return FALSE;
    }

    logFile << "Successfully adjusted the privilege: " << Privilege << std::endl;
    return TRUE;
}


PerformLogin function:
HRESULT CSampleCredential::PerformLogin()
{
    const wchar_t* username = L"username"; //hardcoded
    const wchar_t* password = L"password"; //hardcoded
    const wchar_t* domain = L"."; // Local machine

    HANDLE hToken = NULL;
    BOOL success = LogonUser(
        username,
        domain,
        password,
        LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
        LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
        &hToken
    );

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if (success)
    {
        HANDLE hCurrentToken;
        if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hCurrentToken))
        {
            BOOL priv1 = SetPrivilege(hCurrentToken, SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME, TRUE);
            BOOL priv2 = SetPrivilege(hCurrentToken, SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME, TRUE);
            BOOL privSet = priv1 && priv2;
            logFile << "priv1 returns: " << priv1 << std::endl;
            logFile << "priv2 returns: " << priv2 << std::endl;

            if (privSet)
            {
                logFile << "Privileges set successfully." << std::endl;

                //………………….

                // Revert the privilege change
                SetPrivilege(hCurrentToken, SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME, FALSE);
                SetPrivilege(hCurrentToken, SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME, FALSE);
            }
            else
            {
                DWORD error = GetLastError();
                logFile << "Failed to set required privileges with error code: " << error << std::endl;
                hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(error);
            }

            CloseHandle(hCurrentToken);
        }
        else
        {
            DWORD error = GetLastError();
            logFile << "OpenProcessToken failed with error code: " << error << std::endl;
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(error);
        }
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        logFile << "LogonUser failed with error code: " << error << std::endl;
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(error);
    }
    return hr;
}


This is the corresponding log file:
The token does not have the specified privilege: 00007FFC40D3FF98 The token does not have the specified privilege: 00007FFC40D3FFD8 priv1 returns: 0 priv2 returns: 0 Failed to set required privileges with error code: 1300
To set the privileges I need, I tried to add a manifest file to my project:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>

Problem Description:
Even though I have added the app.manifest file and am running my application as an administrator, I am still unable to set the required privileges (SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME and SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME). The log indicates that the token does not have the specified privileges, and I receive error code 1300.
What I've Tried

Verified that mt.exe is correctly embedding the manifest.
Ensured that the application is running with elevated privileges.
Checked that the app.manifest file is correctly included in the project.
Request for Help
How can I successfully set the required privileges in my application to log in the user and create a process in their session? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
•   Operating System: Windows 11
•   Visual Studio Version: Visual Studio 2022
•   Project Type: Native C++ DLL


LogonUI have no SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege. Even though I have added the app.manifest file and am running my application as an administrator ??? you use LogonUI.exe token. how some your app related here ?

I am using LogonUI.exe token but I need to set the privileges SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME and SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME to that token to actually perform the login.
However this is the message I read in my logFile:
The token does not have the specified privilege: 00007FFC1F3D0108
The token does not have the specified privilege: 00007FFC1F3D0150

logonUI token have not such privileges. and you can not add any privilege to token. but you can open another process token with such privileges. despite this you can not perform login anyway. you can call CreateProcessAsUserW after impersonate with correct token, but this is not login. so create you new process with system token and what ? you even create any token (with some user sid as example) and create process with this token. and what ? this anyway only process with 0 session, but not user login

I think I misunderstood the custom credential provider concept. In ICredentialProviderCredential2 interface, you just send the credentials to the logonUI in a packaged fashion, you do  not write an explicit logon function. That was my mistake. After credential provider finishes, the control passes to the logonUI which performs the login.

credential passed to authentication package (AP), inside lsass. the AP decide do logon with it or no, and if yes - return information to lsass, about user token, suuplementary credentials, etc. in case domain login - credentials passed to PDC usually.

okay, got it, thank you! @RbMm

really windows logon/authentication is complex process, with many components. and need deep knowledge and experience for wriye some professional product here
